# Android stock browser flexbox not respecting value

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a footer on my mobile page using flexbox. It's looking great on Chrome & Safari but causing a bit of problem in **Android Stock Browsers**. I'm creating it on the fly with javascript & here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h3msgaa/) containing generated html for it.

In short my footer structure is:

```
<container>
    <imgContainer></imgContainer>
    <msgContainer></msgContainer>
    <logoContainer></logoContainer>
</container>
```

All of the elements in **"container"** is having flex with a row direction (is available in the fiddle).

Problem is when I'm using **'-webkit-box'** instead of **'flex'** or **'-webkit-flex'**, my imageContainer is getting smaller than msgContainer in width - although the ratio of **imageContainer:msgContainer is 6:5**. I've tested in **Stock Browsers** on Samsung S3, S5, S7 Edge, Nexus 6P and all are yielding same problem. It'll be great if someone can point out what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `flex` then? I don't think there's some other solution here... Some browsers can interpret some values in a wrong way, this is why we have to help them out with autoprefixer. Maybe they are using a weird version of Webkit which differentiates between `-webkit-box` and `flex`.

Comment: To support flex in Android Stock Browser you definitely need to use `-webkit-box`. So once, using `flex` works it fine in latest Androids but doesn't respect when it runs on Android 4.4.2 or less (which I must support)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your CSS in the question.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using both syntaxes, with the standard `flex` coming second so that it overrides `-webkit-box` for browsers that support it?